# The size of a font

Tags: fontsize

I have to rewrite the text I have here, but I cant find the same "size" of a font.
I am doing it this way:

`\fontsize{10.4pt}{16pt}\selectfont`

and it is close to the result, but still not the same. I cant change the font, but it gives me warnings (see below in comments).

This is my preamble:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} 
 \usepackage{czech,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,multicol} 
 \pagestyle{empty} 
 \topmargin0pt \headheight0pt \headsep0pt 
 \oddsidemargin0pt \evensidemargin0pt 
 \setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth} 
 \addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in} 
 \setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight} 
 \addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}
```

How it can be changed?

Comment: And what's the result you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Something between 10pt and 11pt I think.

Comment: What fonts are you using? It's a scalable font? Do you get any warnings with your code? Can you provide please a minimal, complete document showing the relevant settings?

Comment: The font is a default one. And when I try to do something like \fontsize{10.444pt}{16pt}\selectfont, it gives me warnings: Font shape IL2/cmr/m/n in size 10.444 not avail., substituted for 10pt.

Comment: Then your font doesn't provide the required size. Try with `lmodern`: `\usepackage{lmodern}`.

Comment: I cant change the font. It has to be the same as the printed one.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina `fix-cm` will fix T1 and OT1 but not IL2 which appears to be `cslatex/base/il2cmr.fd`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah, you're right. I'll delete that comment.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: i would guess he's not using cm fonts at all.  of course, without an mwe one can't be sure, but the encoding "il2" isn't one i recognise.  it probably is possible to do arbitrary sizes with the op's font, but we can't be sure, and we can't necessarily say how it's done.

Comment: @user32680 You should really always provide a _complete_ document that shows the problem. It seems the font you are using is available in scalable form so you could modify the fd declarations in the comment above to allow any size, as is done for T1 encoding in fix-cm,

Comment: @wasteofspace cslatex

Answer (score 3):

Please always post a complete document not just fragments. The following shows how to redefine the font declarations to allow the font to be specified at any size.

The `\showoutput` log trace confirms

```
....\IL2/cmr/m/n/10.4 h
....\IL2/cmr/m/n/10.4 e
....\IL2/cmr/m/n/10.4 l
....\IL2/cmr/m/n/10.4 l
....\IL2/cmr/m/n/10.4 o
```

So `hello` in  10.4 font size of this font.

Note I changed the calling of `czech` as TexLive 2013 babel produces an error on your preamble

```
! Package babel Error: You have used an old interface to call babel
(babel)                You may expect compatibility problems wit other packages
.
```

Test document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article} 
 \usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,multicol} 
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
 \pagestyle{empty} 
 \topmargin0pt \headheight0pt \headsep0pt 
 \oddsidemargin0pt \evensidemargin0pt 
 \setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth} 
 \addtolength{\textwidth}{-2in} 
 \setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight} 
 \addtolength{\textheight}{-2in}
\input{il2enc.def}
\DeclareFontFamily{IL2}{cmr}{\hyphenchar\font45 }
\DeclareFontShape{IL2}{cmr}{m}{n}
     {<-5> csr5
      <6-7> csr6
      <7-8> csr8
      <8-9> csr9
      <9-12> csr10
      <12-17> csr12
      <17-> csr17
     }{}


\begin{document}
\fontencoding{IL2}\fontsize{10.4pt}{16pt}\selectfont\showoutput
hello
\end{document}
```